# How to set the distance between two models?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'm looking for methods to set the distance between the two models, because after loading these models, one model is inside the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use placement transformation (translation, rotation and scaling) in your options to load the model - see more [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.compose)

```
var loadOptions = {
      placementTransform: THREE.Matrix4, //your transform matrix goes here 
       globalOffset:{x:0,y:0,z:0}
    };
...
viewer.loadModel(svfPath,loadOptions)
```

See live sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/g8sp9tvn/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable help. The problem is that I load models by their urn, not by svf, as you do. Could you offer me some alternative solution to this situation?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd certainly have figured that out yourself if you checked the official tut to obtain document meta of an URN and get the svfUrl [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/).

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand. Do I need to convert the urn to svfUrl?

Comment: It is also not clear why, after using your code, my models merged into each other. Maybe somewhere I set the wrong value?

Comment: No conversion whatsoever - svfUrl points to the deriviate (SVF in our case) directly and URN refers to the model document. See the official code sample in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, your help is invaluable.